# How to update filters on dynamic data tables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some filters on columns D:K, and which show dynamic data depending on validation validation box as you can see in the gif below. When I choose "Active" 6 rows appear, then when I choose "Sold", more than 6 rows appear. However the new rows are out of filters range.

[image]

**Problem:** How can I update the filters automatically upon data validation change to include more or less rows?

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KthGhCQ0Mm2LFBk_eh_LS7jyXadVuyJpfu9sYm7SzpA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In your situation, how are the values of the columns "D" to "K" updated? I think that in this case, it is required to use Google Apps Script. So, if you have already used a script, I would like to confirm it. And, in your showing image, I cannot understand the cell coordinates. So, can I ask you about the range of cell of the dropdown list you want to edit?

Comment: Columns D:K are using formulas to be updated not app script. Yes I think an app script is required for my request. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to refresh the basic filter when the dropdown list is changed and the values of columns "D" to "K" are updated.

In your situation, I thought that this sample script of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65359377/7108653) might be useful. But, in your situation, when the modification points of the script might be a bit complicated. So, here, I would like to propose the modified script of the sample as a sample script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, please set the sheet name and the cell A1Notation of the dropdown list, and save the script. When you run this script, please edit the dropdown list. By this, this script is automatically run.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const dropDownCell = "B3"; // Please set the range of dropdown list.

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.getA1Notation() != dropDownCell) return;

  // Here, the existing basic filter is refreshed.
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    const range = filter.getRange();
    for (let i = range.getColumn(), maxCol = range.getLastColumn(); i <= maxCol; i++) {
      const filterCriteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(i)
      if (filterCriteria) {
        filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(i, filterCriteria);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- About `const dropDownCell = "B3";`, unfortunately, from your showing sample image, I cannot understand the cell range of the dropdown list. So, please set this and save the script.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

### Added:

From your provided sample Spreadsheet, when I saw it, it seems that the values are not filtered while you add the basic filter. And, when the dropdown list is changed, the basic filter is refreshed by my script. From this situation, I thought that you might have wanted to set the basic filter to the data range. If my understanding is correct, please test the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "My Orders"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const dropDownCell = "B4"; // Please set the range of dropdown list.

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.getA1Notation() != dropDownCell) return;

  // Here, the existing basic filter is refreshed.
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    filter.remove();
  }
  const values = sheet.getRange("D3:K" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const row = values.length - [...values].reverse().findIndex(r => r.findIndex(c => c.toString() != "") > -1) + 2;
  sheet.getRange("D3:K" + row).createFilter();
}
```

- In this sample script, when you change the dropdown list, the basic filter is set to the data range of "D3:K".

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply! I just tried your script and it doesn't work. The dropdown cell is B4.

Comment: @MrFrank Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for the inconvenience and for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `I just tried your script and it doesn't work. The dropdown cell is B4.`. Because, when I tested my sample script when the dropdown list is changed, the basic filter is updated. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue, for example, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for confirming your current issue?

Comment: Hello, here you are: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KthGhCQ0Mm2LFBk_eh_LS7jyXadVuyJpfu9sYm7SzpA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @MrFrank Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that the values are not filtered while you add the basic filter. And, when the dropdown list is changed, the basic filter is refreshed. From this situation, I thought that you might have wanted to set the basic filter to the data range. For my guessing, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.