# Activate/Deactivate Filter Using Checkbox In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I use Filter By Condition > Is Not Empty in Google Sheets to hide empty rows when I do not need to add anything new to my sheet and I set it to Filter By Condition > None when I want to view the empty rows to add new things to the list.

Is there any way to add a checkbox to a cell and have it Filter By Condition when checked and not filter when its unchecked so that I can just click the checkbox instead of opening up the filter and selecting None or Not Empty whenever I want to switch?

I found a method that someone used to only display certain things, such as only rows with Tshirt or Jeans in them, but that seems to only compare two rows and not use the Filter By Condition. I tried to see if I could modify that to get it to hide the empty rows but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting from the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72428311/how-to-update-filters-on-dynamic-data-tables) you could create a checkbox that let's you choose if you want the blanks to be filtered or not and have an onEdit function to update when the checkbox is updated or not.

In my example, the checkbox is in B1 and the range to be filtered is A2:A:

[image]

Then, I chose filtering by condition and Custom Formula:

[image]

With this formula:

```
=IF($B$1,NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),A2=A2)
```

Then, you can open the console in Extensions - Apps Script and paste this code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var r = e.range
  var ns = r.getSheet().getName()
  var cell = r.getA1Notation()

  if(ns == "Sheet1" && cell == "B1"){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    const filter = sheet.getFilter();
      if (filter) {
        const range = filter.getRange();
        for (let i = range.getColumn(), maxCol = range.getLastColumn(); i <= maxCol; i++) {
          const filterCriteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(i)
          if (filterCriteria) {
            filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(i, filterCriteria);
          }
        }
      }
    
  }
}
```

Execute it once with that "Run" option. It **will** throw error the first time, but you need it to accept the permissions

[image]

Then, you can tick and untick the checkbox and it will update:

[image]

Comment: I can't add that script because when I click on the App Scripts because it opens a new tab and says Bad Request Error 400

Comment: Do you have more than one account open in your browser?, If so, are you probably using not the main account to open this spreadsheet? Two options: open a new browser with this account, or share the spreadsheet with edit access to the main account

Comment: That seemed to be the problem as I opened it in a Private window and it worked. However the Run option is greyed out so I cant run it.

Comment: Nevermind, guess I had to save it before the run option became available.

Comment: Yeah it worked. Though I had to modify it a bit so it could work on more than one sheet cause just copying it would make it only work on the last one. Thanks a lot. ^.^