# Google Sheets REGEXMATCH cell or TEXTJOIN as argument

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a filter view for Google Sheets with custom formula as filter condition.
The cells I'm trying to filter on can be single or multi valued (comma separataded) like "Abc", "Def Xyz" or "Abc, Def Xyz".

It works "manually" with `=REGEXMATCH(A3:A, "Abc|Def Xyz")`.
Now I want to filter that based on the value of a cell, which may have values like "Abc", "Def Xyz" or "Abc, Def Xyz".

I made a Formula that changes the cells value in the regex format with pipes: `=TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, ArrayFormula(TRIM(SPLIT(A2, ","))))` but it wont work both if I put the Formula in a cell and reference that in the REGEXMATCH and put the TEXTJOIN in the REGEXMATCH directly:

`=REGEXMATCH(A3:A, B1)`

`=REGEXMATCH(A3:A, TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, ArrayFormula(TRIM(SPLIT(A2, ",")))))`

I ended up asking ChatGPT about it and after a while it said:

> Unfortunately, as of 2021, it's not possible in Google Sheets to use a cell as an argument for a regex operation within a filter view.

Is this true? Is there no way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in Conditional Formatting, custom formula filters work as you were going to drag the formula. Create the formula as if it were meant for A3, but you want to "copy" it down the rest of the range; then you need to anchor ($) the 2 in A2. So try with:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A3, TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, ArrayFormula(TRIM(SPLIT(A$2, ",")))))
```

Comment: That almost worked for me, thanks! I had to change A3 to A3:A then it worked:
`=REGEXMATCH(A3:A, TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, ArrayFormula(TRIM(SPLIT(A$2, ",")))))` But when I change the value in A2 the filter only updates when I click "Ok" in the filter view popup again. There's probably no way to change that is there?

Comment: I'm glad you could manage it! Unfortunately there's no built in option for it, but you can see @Tanaike 's answer in questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72428311/how-to-update-filters-on-dynamic-data-tables), and adapt it to your ranges; it re-creates the filter when the cell you specify is modified

Comment: Thanks for your very fast answer! :D But that only works for filters not filter views does it?

Comment: I've been looking a while ago, but haven't found a way to update filter views with Apps Script yet! Please let me know if you happen to find one!!

Comment: I found a way: https://pastebin.com/tbS9ZEfL You have to manually add the onEdit trigger as trigger so it's not a simple trigger anymore and has authentication and add some OAuth scopes in appscript.json and also add Sheets service.

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

> ***NOTE**: If you think your question has been misinterpreted, please clarify it again and include examples of your data and desired results.*

According to my understanding, you want to filter any cells in Column **A** that match values like `Abc`, `Def Xyz` or `Abc, Def Xyz` using the [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292) function in a ***[filter view](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681#cke_bm_3406C)*** on your sheet.

To visualize my understanding, say you have these column `A` values:

[image]

And you want to filter out the cells using ***filter views***:

[image]

If this is the case, you may try this sample ***REGEXMATCH*** formula as a custom formula in your filter view:

`REGEXMATCH(A3:A,"(?i)(\babc, def xyz\b|\babc\b|\bdef xyz\b)")`

> *This formula matches all cells that contain `Abc`, `Def Xyz` or `Abc, Def Xyz` *(using a word boundary `\b`)* regardless of case sensitivity *(using `(?i)`)*.*

### Reference

- [Regex Word Boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- [Regex case insensitive modifier `(?i)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you got me wrong. :[ Martins answer works for my problem. Thanks for your effort though!